# Producer Threads blocked on ActiveMQConnection.ensureConnectionInfoSent()

Tags: activemq-classic

I have a ThreadPoolExecutor which runs a worker to post messages to the ActiveMQ 5.15.3.

Each worker tries to get connection from the PooledConnectionFactory. And then tries to post the message on the Queue.

**Am not sure why almost all the threads on the messagePool are getting blocked on the createSession call ? **

[image]

**I have added the thread dump below :**

> messagePool-1 - threadId:85 - state:BLOCKED
>   stackTrace
>   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED
>   at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.ensureConnectionInfoSent(ActiveMQConnection.java:1469)
>   - waiting to lock <69f3e6c8> (a java.lang.Object) owned by "messagePool-73" t@247
>   at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.createSession(ActiveMQConnection.java:329)
>   at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.ConnectionPool.makeSession(ConnectionPool.java:112)
>   at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.ConnectionPool$1.makeObject(ConnectionPool.java:82)
>   at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.ConnectionPool$1.makeObject(ConnectionPool.java:78)
>   at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.create(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1041)
>   at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:357)
>   at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:279)
>   at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.ConnectionPool.createSession(ConnectionPool.java:144)
>   at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnection.createSession(PooledConnection.java:167)
>   at com.azuga.jms.producer.AMQProducer.postMessage(AMQProducer.java:112)
>   at com.azuga.jms.producer.AMQProducer.postMessage(AMQProducer.java:88)
>   at com.azuga.jms.PostMessagesToAppQueuesWorker.run(PostMessagesToAppQueuesWorker.java:61)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Locked ownable synchronizers:
>   - locked <27cf6e63> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when the client is configured to use a failover transport based URI and the remote broker is either not there, or you've given the wrong address etc.  The client has not connected and is waiting for the initial connection to be established.  You can set options to control how many attempts are made before a failure is reported but in that case the pool is going to keep trying to make new connections to replace the one's that are failing so the real fix is to address the cause of the client not being able to connect.

Comment: I haven't configured a failover and the broker url is correct.
 Also, when I increases the max number of connections & sessions, the issue doesn't seem to happen. Am not sure why ?   
**pooledConnectionFactory.setMaxConnections(100);
pooledConnectionFactory.setMaximumActiveSessionPerConnection(100);**

Comment: If I give my broker url as : 
"failover:(tcp://10.19.0.221:61616)?randomize=false&timeout=30000"
Does activeMQ considers the localhost as the default failover uri and tries to reconnect, if that is what you meant ?

Comment: You are using failover as your URI has "failover" right there in the start.  The client is blocked trying to connect